# vis.js Timeline weekend dates

Tags: javascript, vis.js, timeline.js

Is there a way to force .vis-grid.vis-saturday and .vis-grid.vis-sunday classes to show.  I set up my timeline grouped by employees to show a monthly view but cannot get the Saturday and Sunday to how.  I have to zoom in for it to show up.  I tried manual add Saturday and Sunday for each employees but the result is not the same, can't get the whole column to shade.  Is there anyway I can achieve the shaded to look like the built-in version with the monthly view?

Thanks

[image: Weekend dates shaded by css (.vis-saturday sunday) but have to zoom in to 2 weeks view]

[image: timeline - manually added weekend (Sat & Sun)]

1st Picture:  Auto shaded with .vis.sunday/saturday classes but have to zoom in to 2 week view to see.
2nd Picture:  Manually added events to Saturday and Sunday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This issues](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/2014) has [already been fixed](https://github.com/almende/vis/commit/ae047363fbc0dc7e43bc61882e766ecaadc99431) in vis.js.